# Convert response into string

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, lxml

If I get an XML response from a URL, how I can convert this response into a string and parse the XML, if I'm using `lxml`?

Okay, i get response convert into string and then I trying parse this response.

```
resp = str(data)
etree.fromstring(resp)
```

And i got this error

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

How I will can convert response into string and parse, without errors? what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think you don't have a string already? What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Frequently you can use lxml to get the web page itself: `lxml.html.parse('http://example.com')`

Comment: If its already valid xml, `lxml.etree.get(url)` may also work.

Comment: Update my question.

Comment: How does the string look like?

Comment: begins `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, and I check type, output `str`

Comment: @Maic, "strings" that begin with b are not strings but bytes. To convert bytes to a string, you must `.decode()` it.

Comment: I'm use decode() and got new error from lxml `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

Comment: Can you execute command `type(resp)` and `print respt` ?